# Youtube iframe api Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, google-api, youtube-iframe-api

so I'm loading a youtube playlist using:

```
event.target.loadPlaylist(videoIds);
```

and I'm getting this error:
[image]

The weird part is the playlist loads fine for about one second,
 and then breaks giving me that error.

sorry heres the surrounding code:

```
        window.tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

        window.firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
        //    after the API code downloads.
        // window.player;
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '480',
                width: '853',
                playerVars: {
                    controls: 1,
                    modestbranding: 1,
                    playsinline: 1,
                    showinfo: 1,
                    iv_load_policy: 3,
                    rel: 0
                },
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }
        window.onPlayerReady = function(event) {
            //wierd 404 errors sometimes
            event.target.loadPlaylist(videoIds, 0, 0, 'large');
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        window.onPlayerStateChange = function(event) {
            console.log('the state changed: '+ event.data);
            if (event.data === 1) {
                console.log(event.target.getDuration());
                globalYoutubePlayerCounter++;
                console.log('youtube player count: ' +globalYoutubePlayerCounter);
            }
            if (globalYoutubePlayerCounter >= 6) {
                /* load the next set of videos */
                globalYoutubePlayerCounter = 0;
                console.log('playlist ended');
                if (that.finalTrackList.length > 0) {
                    that.getNextTenMusic(event.target);
                }else{
                    // recall for general searches;
                    // that.getNextTenGeneral(event.target);
                }
                /* load the next set of videos */
            }
        }
```

All video list is formatted correctly even when I get the error. 
Console.log confirms this.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code around it... Does `event.target` really reference the player? Is `videoIds` a well-formed array? Check by displaying them with _console.log_.

Comment: All video list is formatted correctly even when I get the error. 
Console.log confirms this. Event.target is global and logs correctly in the console.

Comment: It works for me... [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMqDW/). I'll take a look at your code.

Comment: it works 80% of the time for me which is confusing

Comment: Your code works for me if I do this: Try removing the code before `// 3. This function...` and actually putting a _<script>_ tag **after** your code, like so `<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>`. If it works for you, I'll explain.

Comment: okay I'll try that! Maybe videoids is losing context or something
I can get it to fail everytime i do: `window.onPlayerReady = function(event) {
            //wierd 404 errors sometimes
            event.target.loadPlaylist(videoIds, 0, 0, 'large');
        }` I removed video.playVideo()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57435/discussion-between-blex-and-gbachik).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but with `loadVideoById`. For me, the problem was that the player hadn't fully initialized and therefore there really was no method loadVideoById. Maybe if someone faces the same problem, try postponing the call and see if that helps.